# I can't login to my openshift cluster after doing a crc start

Tags: openshift, redhat

I am a master student  doing a research project on openshift using codeready on Fedora. After  doing a crc start I encountered the following error. Does anyone could help me with that please.

oc login -u developer -p developer https://api.crc.testing:6443
W0608 14:51:41.813191   21431 loader.go:223] Config not found: /home/user_id/install/auth/kubeconfig
The server uses a certificate signed by an unknown authority.
You can bypass the certificate check, but any data you send to the server could be intercepted by others.
Use insecure connections? (y/n): y
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: unexpected response: 503

Comment: This looks very much like an internal issue for your CRC setup. Did you already try to do a `crc delete`, `crc setup` and a `crc start` as suggested in the documentation? https://code-ready.github.io/crc/#troubleshooting-unknown-issues_gsg Also, check your `~/.crc/crc.log` file and add any errors to your question so we can investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer I actually solved my issue  BY NOT following this  official documentation https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_codeready_containers/1.11/html/getting_started_guide/using-codeready-containers_gsg

Instead of doing crc oc-env I directly did  oc login -u developer -p developer https://api.crc.testing:6443
Then it prompts Install package 'origin-clients' to provide command 'oc'? Which by answering yes made my unexpected response: 503  disappeared .